# How do you share a static constant global string between two separate applications in Qt?

Tags: qt, global-variables, header-files

I am writing a client and server as separate applications. There are some global strings that both should have access to in order to ensure proper communication between the two. What is the typical method to provide such strings to both applications?

I imagine one possible method would be to place the strings in a header file and distribute that file with both applications. Is there anything in Qt that I can use to obtain an OS-agnostic location to place this header file so both applications will know where to look for it?

I'm looking for a solution that benefits from existing Qt libraries, but any generic approach would work as well. I'm not even sure a "library" is necessary, but so far Qt has helped my applications be OS-agnostic and I don't want to break from that paradigm.

*Update to add clarity*: These global strings would be static and constant - meaning they wouldn't change during runtime, so shared memory isn't needed. I just don't want to have a header file in the client and a header file in the server and then have to always make sure that their contents were exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: `QSettings` should do the trick, too, like @Amartel suggested.

It is persistent and is easily access.  Just make sure that your programs perform `readSettings` and `writeSettings` when necessary, if you want to updated the settings on the fly.  I like the INI format that it has.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-application.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/tools-settingseditor.html

`QSharedMemory` could also work.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsharedmemory.html

Example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-sharedmemory.html

You can also achieve this with a `QLocalServer`.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalserver.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html

Example:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-localfortuneclient.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc-localfortuneserver.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Qt gives a lot of ways of sharing data between processes, but most of them require these processes to share a machine. Since you are implementing a client-server paradigm, I assume your applications would interact with each other, and could be located at different computers. In this case the most common way is to establish a TCP connection and transfer data through TCP socket. Connection settings could be placed in a configuration file (for example `QSettings` with parameter `QSettings::IniFormat`).